# How to get records from a table where some field's value is in camel-case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this,

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC_DEF |
| 31 | AcdEmc |
| 44 | AbcDef |
| 2 | BAA_CC_CD |
| 55 | C_D_EE |

I need a query to get the records which Value is only in camelcase (ex: AcdEmc, AbcDef etc. not ABC_DEF).

Please note that this table has only these two types of string values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [UPPER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055.aspx) for this

```
select * from your_table
where upper(value) <> value COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

If your default collation is case-insensitive you can force a case-sensitive collation in your `where` clause. Otherwise you can remove that part from your query.

Comment: This is what I was going to do as well.  Since you only have two types, determining when a string IS NOT a type (in this case: not all caps) is a good as determining when it is.

Comment: SQL server string comparisons are case-insensitive.

Comment: @MarioJVargas: You ca't say that generally. I updated the answer. It depends on the collation that is used by the DB which is configurable.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc024/7

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've used `varbinary` to do case-sensitive comparisons against a string column.

Comment: Thank you juergen d for the answer. First it did not work but after you add `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` to the query, I ran it and it works.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the sample data, the following will work. I think the issue we're dealing with is checking whether the string contains underscores.

```
SELECT * FROM [Foo]
WHERE Value NOT LIKE '%[_]%';
```

[See Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df2c4/1/0)

**UPDATE**: Corrected error. I forgot '_' meant "any character".

Comment: I agree. I updated my answer because I noticed an error in my LIKE expression. I corrected this.